# Do the timings of my sunnah salaat at home depend on the adhaan in the masjid?

Tags: salat, women, prayer-timings

I have a question regarding the four Sunnahs before Zuhr, especially for ladies who don't pray in the Masjid and therefore can't hear the Adhan.

Do these four Rakaat need to be performed immediately after the Adhan but before the Iqammah (as it is pronounced in the Masjid), or are we allowed to just pray them before our own Zuhr, even if it's after the imam has already started Zuhr in the Masjid?

Comment: Please avoid greetings such as "Assalamualaykum" and take the time to write your question clearly and using proper grammar in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As stated before, you should follow the Salah timetable. It will differ from the place where you live and also from your Mazhab...

Time of Salah is related to the sun's position. One it's Hikmat is that anyone can, when he know the rules, pray just by looking at the sun, without any watch...

I will strongly suggest you to have a look at this small article :

[Timetable  of  Prayers  according  to  sun’s  position  and  mazaahib](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=BFE7F2632AD75D50!1104&authkey=!AIQeSo4s26bz4tY)

Moreover, ladies are encouraged to pray their Salah in the beginning of its time...

Answer (score 0):

Walekumasalam,you can perform Namaz-e-Zuhr when its time start(you can see the time table according to your location). Women are perform 4 rakaat of sunnat before they are going to perform 4 rakaat of Farz.It is not compulsary for women to hear adhan for starting their Namaz or No need to wait for Imam has started in Masjid or not.(Just follow Start and End time of Namaz). You just need to perform your namaz after start time and before ending time please do take care of this time.
Even you can follow [this link](http://www.islamicfinder.org/) for Namaz Time Table for your location.
Or there are number of mobile apps you can dowload mobile application like [muslim pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitsmedia.android.muslimpro) etc.
Thanks..

Comment: even you follow [this link](http://www.islamicfinder.org/) for Namaz time table